# Where can I store my scheduled tasks for continuity?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs, scheduled-tasks

I am using Nestjs. I wrote a function to execute given function after n minutes.

It is here :

```
@Injectable()
export class TasksService {
  constructor(private schedulerRegistry: SchedulerRegistry) {}

  execAfterGivenMinutes(cb: Function, minutes: number) {
    const TIMEOUT_NAME = 'after_minutes_' + nanoid();

    const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      cb();

      this.deleteTimeout(TIMEOUT_NAME);
    }, minutes * 60000);

    this.schedulerRegistry.addTimeout(TIMEOUT_NAME, timeout);
  }

  private deleteTimeout(name: string) {
    this.schedulerRegistry.deleteTimeout(name);
  }
}
```

However, there may be uncompleted tasks when the server crashes for any reason. For example there is a callback that is given the task function to execute after 2 minutes, but after 1 minute the server crashed and task did not complete. I do not want this. What is the possible things that I can do.

I thought storing tasks another server but if there is any solution I won't implement this.

Comment: You could use a cookie to flag when the task is set, and when it completes, and the server can check (including after a shut-down, when re-running) for incomplete tasks and execute as needed. If handling incomplete tasks can be handled client-side, use local storage.

Comment: @DeeGee Thanks. But tasks are not belong to client they are backend tasks. For example deleting a verification code after user signed up.

Comment: Why not use Redis for such a case?